# Can I disable scrolling when touching certain view in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview

I have a [TradingView chart](https://www.tradingview.com/lightweight-charts/) inserted in the scroll view by fragment manager.
I can not smoothly scroll the x-axis and y-axis of the chart because the scroll view will influence it.
Can I disable scrolling the page when toughing the chart view?

Answer (score 0):

The view itself can stop it.  Touch events like this work by intercepting the touch event stream.  When a child view is touched, the parent can request to steal the event stream if it so desires.  The child can stop it by calling requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent.  It needs to call requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) when the touch begins (on the down event) and requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false) when the touch ends (on the up).  If you can't edit the code of the view itself, set an onTouchListener and do so for it.  Make sure the listener returns false so the view's built in touch listener is called as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped my map view which does not intercept scrolling to custom view which intercepts scrolling in parent NestedScrollView:

```
class ScrollLockView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs) {
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        return false
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<my.package.ScrollLockView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <VendorViewNeedLockScrollFor />

                        </my.package.view.ScrollLockView>
```